# text position during changing browser size, video doesn't work ONLY in Firefox

Tags: html, css, video

I have modified a free webside.
Orginal project you can find there:
http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page193/munter

After my changes is there:
http://www.megafileupload.com/o9xK/Munter_Stackoverflow.rar

My problem:
1.
 a) I have added a video. It works in Microsoft Edge and Microsoft Explorer. 
I have problem with Mozzila Firefox. 
I used video from w3school.
Everything is ok with the video on w3school webside, when I see it in my browser in Mozzila Firefox. 
The same video (which I have downloaded) doesn't work in my project web side.
I can see it but the play button doesn't work. 
The video works only after right click on video and choose 'play'.
To stop the video I need right click on video and press 'stop'.

---

```
<html>
 <!-- === SLide 3 - Portfolio -->
    <div class="slide story" id="slide-3" data-slide="3">
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row title-row">
                    <div class="col-12 font-thin"> Tekst 1 <span class="font-semibold"> Tekst 2</span></div>
                </div>
                  <!-- /row -->
                <div class="hr">&nbsp;
                    <div class="video"> 
                        <video controls>
                            <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" preload="true">
                            <source src="images/video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                            <p>Your browser does not support H.264/MP4.</p>
                        </video>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /slide3 -->

</html>
```

---

```
 #slide-3 {
    background-color: #FFCC33;
    color: #e4e6e5;
    padding-top: 90px;
}
.title-row {
        font-size: 34px;        
}

    #video{                             
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto; 
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px gray;
        width: 404px;  /* 320 */
        height: 720px;  /* 568 */
    }

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #slide-3 .col-12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

b) The text over the video is centerd in container, but every time I change the browser window size, it goes to right side.

2. How move 'h1' text "MUNTER DESIGN" up wihtout changing 'slide 2' position.

I tried move 'h1' text up, about 50px under navigation bar. 
When I have changed 'h1' from orginal 130px to 0px (minus doesn't work) like that:

```
    #slide-1 h1 {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

the 'h1' text is about 100px under Navigation bar, and the 'slide 2' is higher.
After I changed 'h1' from 130 to 0, 'slide 2' went about 130px higher.
I want change position of the 'h1' text, not 'slide 2' position. I want 'slide 2' position the same how in oryginal version.

I can't move 'h1' text on the possition I want, very close under navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

1.
a) The video playback problem is caused by jQuery, without the `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` the controls work. I would suggest using an jQuery video player.

b) Use the bootstrap helper `center-block`, this keeps your div centered. Keep in mind, that the position may still change if you change your browser size and don't reload your site.

```
<div class="row title-row center-block">
```

2. In your style.css change the following:

   ```
   #slide-1 h1 {
       margin-top: 0px;
   }

   #home-row-1, #home-row-2 {
       padding-top: 0px;
   }
   ```

   If you want to see which elements effect what in your DOM, use your browsers developer tools.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1.a) I'm reading about jQuery video player.             b) I changed <div class="row title-row"> for <div class="row title-row center-block">, but it didn't fix a problem. The text is on right side. I don't know it is enaught. Maybe there is an error in another place.    2. Your advice about changing in style.css was correct. H1 text  is in the place where I want,  but slide-1 is half it's previous size. I tried to make more space but I can't fix it.

Comment: b) That's weird, have you tried reloading the site after resizing? On hitting the media-queries width the standard bootstrap CSS can mess with such things.
2. If you want to add more height, just add a `padding-bottom` to your `slide-1`, about 100px should give it it's original size.